# Is it possible to apply a custom option to an entire category of products in Magento?

Tags: magento, product, categories

I'm working on a Magento-powered jewelry store and the sample ring I added as a product, I
created a custom option for Ring Size (a SELECT drop down).

Easy enough.

My question is this - how can I apply that custom option to ALL products within the Rings
category?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're wrong with the idea of using custom options here. If you're planning to use **Ring Size** for all of your Rings products, it's better to create a **Ring Size** attribute, add it to "*Rings*" Attribute Group, and use this attribute group to create your Rings products.

Update. You need to use the ***Configurable*** product type for your rings product. Here's the [manual](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product) how to create a Configurable product.

To wrap it up - here's the brief description of Configurable products functional: The actual "configurable" product is a virtual "container" that contain **simple** physical items with concrete attribute option within itself.

In your case you will create a Configurable product that is configured by the attribute **Ring Size**. Then you will create some simple product, each with it's own **Ring Size** option. After simple products are created, you will assign them to the configurable product, so the customer will have the ability to choose the desired **Ring Size** on the frontend.

Just don't forget to mark **Ring Size** attribute as "*is used to create configurable products*" duting the attribute creation.

Comment: How do I create a dropdown attribute, though? I tried creating one once and all it did was show a long list of ring sizes on the page.

Comment: I'm sorry, I actually didn't specify how exactly you can get it to work as a dropdown, give me few moments - I will update my post

Comment: do I need to create a configurable product and a simple product for each ring in my client's catalog?

Comment: Yes, if you want each of your Rings to be configurable by **Ring Size** - you need to create a Configurable product for that ring, and a simple product for each of individual Sizes. I know, it seems like a lot of work - but it will give you benefits. You will have automatic stock management for your physical items (for custom options it's impossible), also you'll be able to use **Ring Size** in Layered Navigation as a filter, if you want.